# Python 3 | automatic open new .exe window and get his position every frame

Tags: python, pywinauto

I'm trying to make a Python 3 code that's open .exe program and get the program window x and y position every frame ( in a while )

my code so far:

```
from pywinauto import application


app = application.Application()
app.start("D:/GameMaker/Progects/Games/tut to next/GMnet-ENGINE-master/Builds/GMnetBaseTemplate/GMnetBaseTemplate.exe")
```

--

so how do I get the window's x and y positions?
Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [window()](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.application.html#pywinauto.application.Application.window) to get application window, and call [rectangle()](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.base_wrapper.html#pywinauto.base_wrapper.BaseWrapper.rectangle) method of base_wrapper class.

```
x = app.window().wrapper_object().rectangle().left
y = app.window().wrapper_object().rectangle().top
```

This also should work:

```
x = app.window().rectangle().left
y = app.window().rectangle().top
```